# Convert unbounded string to integer Ada

Tags: string, ada

My question is rather simple, as Google has let me down. How do I convert an unbounded string to an integer?

If the string was bounded, I could do this: `I : Integer := Integer'Value("613");`

However, my string is unbounded, and Ada throws this error:

`expected type "Standard.String"
found private type "Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String"`

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to do the intermediate conversion:

```
I : Integer := Integer'Value (To_String (T));
```

Here is a full test program:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   T : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String ("613");
   I : Integer := Integer'Value (To_String (T));
begin
   Put_Line (I'Image);
end Main;
```