# How do I convert an unbounded string to an integer?

Tags: ada

I am learning Ada (by trying https://adventofcode.com/2018/ problems). To start with, I am trying to develop a number of "utility" packages that will help with text processing etc.

I have successfully written a function that will read from stdin and return an array of `Unbounded_String`s for each input line.

I am trying to modify that function to do the same, but instead convert each `Unbounded_String` to an `Integer` before insertion into the array.

Here is my package:

get_stdin.ads:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package get_stdin is
  type IntegerArray is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;
  function get_ints return IntegerArray;

end get_stdin;
```

get_stdin.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Strings;

package body get_stdin is

  function get_ints return IntegerArray is
    Counter : Natural := 0;
    Str  : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
    Arr  : IntegerArray(0..10000);
  begin
    while not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File loop
      Str := Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO.Get_Line;
      Arr(Counter) := Integer'Value(Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_String(Str));
      Counter := Counter + 1;
    end loop;

    return Arr(0..Counter-1);
  end get_ints;

end get_stdin;
```

I am calling using this package inside this procedure:

```
procedure d1 is
  StdinArr : get_stdin.IntegerArray := get_stdin.get_ints;

begin
   null; -- Array processing to follow
end;
```

This successfully compiles, and I then pipe in my input text file:

```
me@mypc /cygdrive/c/Users/me/aoc2018

$ cat d1.txt
-6
-1
-18
-10
...etc

me@mypc /cygdrive/c/Users/me/aoc2018
$ cat d1.txt | ./d1.exe

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : bad input for 'Value: "-6"
```

"-6" is the first value in the text file. My string-to-integer conversion code was essentially copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565836/convert-unbounded-string-to-integer-ada).

- I am not sure why a bad input error is raised.
- It raises the same error if I replace -6 with a positive integer in the file
- This is running under Cygwin on Windows 10.
- Compiled/linked with `gnatmake` version 7.3.0

*Note: I'm just getting started with Ada so there's probably lots of issues with my code in general.*

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this function/package to return my `IntegerArray` type correctly filled with `Integer`s?

Comment: It works fine for me (macOS, GNAT CE 2018). Maybe you’ve got a line-ending problem? (though, as I remember, GNAT is fairly resilient in that respect)

Comment: Aaaah, if I pipe the input through dos2unix first it works. Thanks, I'd checked that Get_Line stripped line endings, but hadn't thought about -Windows- line endings specfically.

Comment: You don't actually need to use unbound strings here, Usual String type work fine to read from file

Comment: @TimurSamkharadze I thought about that but then I'd have to specify a maximum size for the length (I think?) and therefore unbounded strings seemed less prone to breaking later on...

Comment: @jfowkes, nope it's not necessarily. You might do it like here https://github.com/timurgen/AdventOfAda/blob/master/2018/3/src/main.adb

Comment: What's wrong with `Integer'Value (Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line)`?

Comment: I used unbounded strings because this :https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO says "They are more efficient and easier to use than the standard Ada.Text_IO functions."

Comment: And I'm still at the "not knowledgeable enough to know what to trust" stage.

Comment: It may be easier if you need Unbounded_Strings, but as all you're doing is converting it to String, you clearly don't. Efficiency is not a concern, unless you're unable to meet your timing requirements, but even then avoiding unneeded use of Unbounded_String will probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This was a line endings issue. I was running under cygwin on Windows 10. My text file has Windows-style line endings.

Using `dos2unix`:

```
$ cat d1.txt | dos2unix.exe | ./d1.exe
```

was sufficient to make it work correctly.

If anyone can explain precisely why, that would be interesting. I'm guessing that `Get_Line` only strips off the `\n` character, not the `\r`.

Comment: why not just use native gnat?

Comment: I'm more familar with linux tools, but just happened to be on a PC running Windows (but with cygwin installed) when I started doing this.